# Range and Value

Tags: excel, vba

How can the contents of a multi-cell range be displayed in a single textbox, is it even possible?

```
Sub ShowContent()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim content As String

    Set rng = Range("A1:C5")

    For Each cell In rng
        content = content & cell.Value & " "
    Next cell

    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Value = content 
End Sub
```

Comment: Your codes seems correct. What problem your facing with?

Comment: If you are using `Set rng = Range("DN:DU22") ` then you are missing a start row number.